# Wordpress admin - add item next to "Activate Edit Delete" list

Tags: wordpress

In the plugins section of the admin screen, each plugin generally has a list of a few things you can do, usually "activate, edit, delete". How can I add an item to this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plugin file just add this code.

```
// Add settings link on plugin page
function your_plugin_settings_link($links) { 
  $settings_link = '<a href="options-general.php?page=your_plugin.php">Settings</a>'; 
  array_unshift($links, $settings_link); 
  return $links; 
}

$plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__); 
add_filter("plugin_action_links_$plugin", 'your_plugin_settings_link' );
```

**EDIT:** OK so i guess you are administrating the sites, and you want your users to report if something goes wrong with any plugin. Here are some of the options.

- Use Jquery to add links.
- Use the above function and add a loop around the add_filter, and then loop through `$all_plugins = get_plugins();

Comment: Thank you Omer, sometimes, when someone answers your question, it helps you refine what you're asking for! I was really asking this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099356/wordpress-add-an-option-for-all-plugins-in-plugins-page