# Wordpress, add an option for all plugins in plugins page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

In /wp-admin/plugins.php, I want to add an option after the "Edit" "Activate" "Settings", but I want to make a link for all plugins, not just the current one. Maybe "Report a Problem" after each one, which then does something. I'm thinking of using jQuery to do this outside of Wordpress, but I was wondering if anyone can think of another way to do it. Is there a hook I could go after?

Answer (score -1):

function custom_menu()
{
    add_menu_page(__('HELLO HERE', 'custom_menu'), __('HELLO HERE', 'custom_menu'), 'activate_plugins', 'HELLO HERE', 'custom_menu_example');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_menu');

create new folder (say 'morning') under your theme.inside that folder create new file for example XYZ.php. paste above code in that file.

Now to include that file, go to functions.php of your theme and define at begining of file below code

require_once( 'mornign/XYZ.php' );

i hope it will help